# File system in hadoop

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

Recently I have started to learn hadoop multi cluster

How the file system work's in hadoop.

For eg. If i have one test.txt file in fully of farmer details. 
Whether I need to upload the file in master HDFS server or in slave server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To know how the Hadoop filesystem works, please refer to book **Hadoop: The Definitive Guide**

For time being, to load a file into HDFS, you only need to run the `-put` or `-copyFromLocal` command from edgenode of the cluster(meaning from where you can run `hadoop` command) and rest will be taken care by Hadoop framework.
Your command may look like

`hadoop fs` set

```
$ hadoop fs -copyFromLocal /home/user1/farmer_details.txt /user/user1
```

or

```
$ hadoop fs -put /home/user1/farmer_details.txt /user/user1
```

You can also try `hdfs dfs` set

```
$ hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal /home/user1/farmer_details.txt /user/user1
```

or

```
$ hdfs dfs -put /home/user1/farmer_details.txt /user/user1
```

where `/home/user1/farmer_details.txt` is the source location in your local file system and  `/user/user1` is the destination location in hadoop filesystem.

To verify the uploaded file, you can run command

```
$ hadoop fs -ls /user/user1
```

You should get `/user/user1/farmer_details.txt` file.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. You have mentioned that /user/user1 is the destination location in hadoop filesystem. Where is this /user/user1 path will be ? whether in master server or slave server.

Comment: You just create this directory using Hadoop fs -  mkdir.  It's metadata will be stored on Namenode ie. Master node. When you will load data then data will be stored on Datanode ie. Slave node.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. So the files will be store in Datanode(Slave) and that can be access using the Hadoop in master server. I understand now. Can I have your email id: Still I have lot of doubt in hadoop

Answer (score 2):

first, you need to upload the file:text.txt to one node of the cluster(can be master server or slave server), eg, upload to /tmp foler and you got: /tmp/text.txt, then use the command:

```
# hadoop fs -put /tmp/text.txt /tmp
```

then use command:

```
# hadoop fs -ls /tmp
```

you will find the file:text.txt has already in that hdfs folder:/tmp

Comment: you can not cat a directory

Comment: "hadoop fs -put /tmp/text.txt /tmp"


Suppose if I create a tmp folder in datanode 1 (Slaver server) how that can be access in the master server like /tmp/text.txt and where is the /tmp folder exist whether in master or slave. If it is HDFS then whether the whole test.txt file will be upload in master server or the metadata of that file. Please explain me more clearly about this

Comment: Yes, please change cat to ls of that command which can list the content of the folder. The metadata of the file is stored in the namenode server and the content of the file is stored in the slave servers. In the master server or namenode server, you can still use Hadoop command to access the file in the slave severs